# VSCode editor not marking changes

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed that the VSCode editor sometimes mark/track changes (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNnHA.jpg where there's a blue mark next to line 16 to indicate a change) and sometimes it doesn't, and today it's not tracking changes for some reasons, and I am not sure what's causing the issue.

Could someone advise how to debug this issue?

Comment: Is the file in a repo?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes it is

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by the setting `scm.diffDecorations`.  By default, it should be set to all:

[image: Diff decorations]

Check this setting.  Additionally, new files that you just added can't show these differences, because it (Git) has nothing to compare it to yet. The same can be said for untracked files.